# Coupled quantum harmonic oscillator: Decomposition in terms of number basis representation for numerical implementation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, computational-physics, software, coupled-oscillators

Consider the Hamiltonian of a coupled quantum harmonic oscillator

\begin{align}
  \hat{H}&=\frac{1}{2m}(p_1^2+p_2^2)+\frac{m\omega^2}{2}(q_1^2+q_2^2)+\alpha(q_2-q_1)^2
\\&=\frac{1}{2m}(p_1^2+p_2^2)+(\frac{m\omega^2}{2}+\alpha)(q_1^2+q_2^2)-2\alpha q_1q_2\tag{1}
\end{align}
with $$[q_n,p_m]=i\delta_{nm}
$$ and the other commutators as usual.

We can do the following two transformations to diagonalise it:
First, let
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
q_1\\q_2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\tilde{q}_1\\\tilde{q}_2
\end{pmatrix},\qquad \begin{pmatrix}
p_1\\p_2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\tilde{p}_1\\\tilde{p}_2
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

This transformation preserves the commutators, i.e. $[\tilde{q}_k,\tilde{p}_l]=i\delta_{kl}$. Substituting this transformation, we obtain the Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
  \hat{H}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{N=2}\frac{1}{m}\tilde{p}_k^2+m\omega_k^2\tilde{q}_k^2
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $\omega_1=\sqrt{\omega^2+\frac{4\alpha}{m}}, \,\,\,\omega_2=\omega$.

Secondly, we can define ladder operators $a_k,a_k^{\dagger}$ for $k\in\{1,2\}$:
\begin{equation}
a_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m\omega_k}}\left(m\omega_k\tilde{q}_k+i\tilde{p}_k\right),\qquad a_k^{\dagger}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m\omega_k}}\left(m\omega_k\tilde{q}_k-i\tilde{p}_k\right)
\end{equation}
satisfying $[a_k,a_l^{\dagger}]=\delta_{kl}$. Hence,
\begin{equation}
 \tilde{q}_k =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m\omega_k}}(a_k+a_{k}^{\dagger}), \qquad \tilde{p}_k=-i\sqrt{\frac{m\omega_k}{2}}(a_k-a_{k}^{\dagger})
\end{equation}

This finally gives a Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
\hat{H}=\sum_{k=1}^{N=2}\omega_k(a_k^{\dagger}a_k+\frac{1}{2})\tag{2}
\end{equation}

I want to implement this model numerically. Let's say I want to compute the interaction energy with corresponding Hamiltonian $\hat{H}_I=-2\alpha q_1 q_2$ for a global thermal state $\rho=e^{-\beta\hat{H}}/Tr[e^{-\beta\hat{H}}]$ at inverse temperature $\beta$. This amounts to computing
\begin{equation}
E_I=Tr[\hat{H}_I\rho]
\end{equation}
I can easily write the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$ as a matrix in the number basis (and choosing some finite cutoff dimension $d$, with mode number operator $\hat{n}_k=\hat{a}_k^{\dagger}a_k$.

To express the interaction Hamiltonian $\hat{H}_I$ as a matrix in this basis using ladder operators, I express it as
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\hat{H}_I=-2\alpha q_1 q_2=\alpha(\tilde{q}_1^2-\tilde{q}_2^2)\\
=-\frac{\alpha}{2m}(-\frac{1}{\omega_1}(a_1^2+(a_1^{\dagger})^2+2a_1^{\dagger}a_1+1)+\frac{1}{\omega_2}(a_2^2+(a_2^{\dagger})^2+2a_2^{\dagger}a_2+1))
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Is this correct? Choosing each QHO to have ladder operators of dimension $d$, I express them using

```
def a(d):
    a = np.zeros((d,d))
    for i in range(d-1):
        a[i][i+1] = np.sqrt(i+1)
    return a

def adag(d):
    return np.conjugate(a(d).T)

a1 = np.kron(a(d), np.identity(d))
a2 = np.kron(np.identity(d), a(d))
a1dag = np.kron(adag(d), np.identity(d))
a2dag = np.kron(np.identity(d), adag(d))

ident = np.kron(np.identity(d), np.identity(d))

om1 = np.sqrt(omega**2+4*alpha/m)
om2 = omega


tildeq1=1/(np.sqrt(2*m*om1))*(a1+a1dag)
tildeq2=1/(np.sqrt(2*m*om2))*(a2+a2dag)

q1=1/np.sqrt(2)*(tildeq1+tildeq2)
q2=1/np.sqrt(2)*(-tildeq1+tildeq2)


H= om1*(a1dag@a1+1/2*ident)+om2*(a2dag@a2+1/2*ident) 
H_check = 1/(2m)(p1@p1+p2@p2)+(m*omega**2/2+alpha)(q1@q1+q2@q2)-2alpha*q1@q2 

HI=-2*alpha*q1@q2
```

Somehow H and H_check are not the same, using my method. What is going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean that you do not get the correct results numerically? More specifically, what do you expect to obtain and what do you obtain instead?

Comment: my implementation does not seem to be correct as I get two different results for the global Hamiltonian for the different methods. The first method is matrix ```H= om1*(a1dag@a1+1/2*ident)+om2*(a2dag@a2+1/2*ident) ``` with  ```ident = np.kron(np.identity(d), np.identity(d)) ``` and the second method is  ```H=1/(2m)(p1@p1+p2@p2)+(m*omega**2/2+alpha)(q1@q1+q2@q2)-2alpha*q1@q2 ```

Comment: So you want to compare Eq (1) to Eq (2) (labels that I've just added)?? Your code only shows $H\sim q_1q_2$, so it's kind of hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Wait; you've defined $a_k$ and $a_k^\dagger$ in terms of $\tilde{p}_k$ and $\tilde{q}_k$, so is your code actually computing $H\sim\tilde{q}_1\tilde{q}_2$ instead?

Comment: I updated my question, it is computing the actual interaction Hamiltonian. The main consistency check is whether H is equal to H_check, which does not work for me.

Comment: Hmm. I'm getting identical results if I compare Eq (1) with $H=\{\sum_k\tilde{p}_k^2/m+m\omega_k^2\tilde{q}_k^2\}/2$. When comparing Eqs (1) & (2), it is only the `H[d][d]` value that seems to be different from `H_check[d][d]`. Is this what you observe?

Comment: Oh I see, I now get the same. It is because I only set d=2.